# How to call function when variable is available in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In **geocodePosition** function  which generates place_id, which is use by `service.getDetails` in same function(geocodePosition). But problem is that this code is not stop till get **place_id** and go to **service.getDetails** which is using place_id, which is not generated yes. **So how to wait till place_id is generated.**

```
function geocodePosition(pos){

   geocoder.geocode({ latLng: pos}, function(responses){
     $scope.place_id=responses[0].place_id;
     console.log('$scope.place_id'+$scope.place_id);
   });

  var map=$scope.map.control.getGMap();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  $scope.$watch(function(){
    return $scope.place_id
  }, function(place_id){
    service.getDetails({placeId: place_id}, function(place, status){
      console.log('place'+place);
    });
  });

}//End of geocodePosition
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `$watch` your `$scope.place_id` variable and call the `getDetails` if changes.

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return $scope.place_id;
}, function(place_id) {
  if (!place_id) {
    return;
  }
  service.getDetails({ placeId: place_id }, function(place, status) {
    console.log('place='+place);
  });
});
```

Comment: I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function `  for `$scope.watch(function(){`

Comment: It has to be `.$watch`, not `.watch`

Comment: still I am getting Error but now error is `Error: Missing parameter. You must specify placeId.`

Comment: @geeks So you should avoid passing empty variable. Check again my edit.

Answer (score 0):

As `geocoder.geocode` is asynchronous: Use $q for introcing promises in your code.

For example:

```
function geocodePosition(pos){
  q = $q.defer;
  geocoder.geocode({ latLng: pos}, function(responses){
    var place_id=responses[0].place_id;
    console.log('$scope.place_id'+$scope.place_id);
    q.resolve(place_id);
  }
 };

geocodePosition(pos).then(function(place_id){
  //use it here... 
});
```

Comment: I am getting Uncaught ReferenceError: $q is not defined

Comment: You need to inject it into your controller / factory...
`app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $q) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});`

Comment: I already injected but still Getting same error `controller.$inject = ['$scope', '$q'] ; function controller($scope, $q) {`